# An expression that expresses I know someone can do their job

Tags: expressions

I complained to a company about one of their employees, and tomorrow the
owner is going to call me in to explain myself.

I know for a fact that he is going to say what he has done to that employee
and what kind of things he said to him. But it's important, logistically, that
I tell him that I know he (the boss) can do his job well and what he told the
employee doesn't really concern me, that all I want to do is solve the issue.

How can I say that? How can I say "I know you can do your job well;
what you told him doesn't concern me" in a single expression?

In Portuguese we have a saying that "one knows how to fry his chicken",
which means that I know he knows how to deal with the employee.

Is there such an expression in English?

Comment: You can just say, “I trust you, I don’t need the details.”

Answer (score 1):

You could say that your boss **runs a tight ship**.

> *run a tight ship:* to run a ship or an organization in an orderly and disciplined manner.
>
> *The new office manager really runs a tight ship.*

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+a+tight+ship)

.........

> *run a tight ship:* to control a business or other organization firmly and effectively
>
> *Ruth runs a tight ship and has no time for shirkers.*

[Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+a+tight+ship)

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to express it is something like, "It's not my place to tell you how to do your job.  I only care about the outcome."

If it's an informal setting and you want to keep the tone light, you could say something like, "Dealing with this stuff is why they pay **you** the big bucks.  I'm glad the situation is in good hands."  (It isn't really commentary on the person's salary.  It's more an implication that they deserve high pay for having to handle tough situations.)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how [formal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)) the setting is.

In an *informal* setting, the phrase 'John knows his shit' is an exact match.

A less-emphatic but also less-precise version used in more formal settings is 'John knows his job', or perhaps 'John is *competent* at his job' if you prefer, since that word implies both knowledge and skill at something.